# yii2: how to send a model from a create form to the controller

Tags: forms, model, frameworks, yii2

I have a dropdownlist in my form:

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'Id_tipoprograma',
  ArrayHelper::map(Tipoprograma::find()->all(), 'Id_tipoprograma', 'Id_tipoprograma', 'Descripcion'))?>
```

i want to receive "Id_tipoprograma" in the controller, i tried with:

```
$idtp = $model->Id_tipoprograma;
```

But doesn't work. thanks.

Comment: First read docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html). Normally you should get form data in ```Yii::$app->request->post()```

Comment: I have added this as an answer. Can you please accept it as valid answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html). Normally you should get form data in `Yii::$app->request->post()` or `Yii::$app->request->get()`